# How to analyse timestamp in ext4 manually?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, timestamp, journaling

I am doing research on Ext4 and I believe I understand the fundamentals of Ext4.

Ext4 stores timestamps. In my assignment, I have proposed to analyse the timestamp of Ext4 MANUALLY instead of typing the command (e.g. `date -d @2220775699`).

Is there a way to do so?

In addition, why does the timestamp different from the timestamp in the journaling?

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Isn't it just a normal [Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_timestamp)?

Comment: I believe so? I'm analysing it in Ubuntu.

Comment: What do you mean by "manually"?  To me, that means "by hand" which seems to be exactly what you are trying to avoid.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko: The `date` command is a standard Unix timestamp, but the Ext4 timestamp isn't. Ext4 supports fractional seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to translate timestamps to human-friendly description of date and time, then obviously there is a way to do it.

The functions [localtime and gmtime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) are made specifically for this purpose; in glibc, they are implemented in terms of a function `__tz_convert`, which is implemented in a file [tzset.c](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=time/tzset.c;h=4f8af8d523efa69453c4eaa49861fca26a4fbfb3;hb=master). You'll probably need to review other functions it uses, though, I haven't studied all of it - GNU source is never easy to read.

**UPD:** `__tz_convert` uses [__offtime](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=time/offtime.c;h=035f71c1534cfcb4e9e978670b7e6278dd579c14;hb=master) internally.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible:

```
debugfs -R `stat /file/to/check\` /dev/hdX
```

I'm not sure which two timestamps you're comparing, so I can't explain the difference. (I.e. if you ask a question about a difference, at least tell us between which two things!)